# An ODE for tensor - possibility of the equation together with the initial condition at $t=0$ deciding the solution for all $t>0$

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

Let $A_{ijl}(t,x) : [0,\infty) \times \mathbb{R}^n \to [\mathbb{R}^n]^3$ be a smooth tensor field. That is, $i,j,l \in \{1,2,3, \cdots, n\}$

Further assume that $A_{ijl}(t,x)=A_{jil}(t,x)$ for all $(t,x) \in [0,\infty) \times \mathbb{R}^n$.

Also, let $0=\lambda_1< \lambda_2 < \cdots < \lambda_n$ be some fixed numbers and finally suppose that $A_{ijl}(t,x)$ satisfies the following ODE:
\begin{equation} 
\partial_t \sum_{l=1}^n A_{ijl}(t,x)= -\sum_{l=1}^n \lambda^2_l A_{ijl}(t,x) \text{ with } \sum_{l=1}^n A_{ijl}(0,x)=\delta_{ij}
\end{equation}

Then, at least when $t=0$, we have
\begin{equation}
\partial_t \sum_{l=1}^n A_{ssl}(t,x)\mid_{t=0}=-\lambda^2_s
\end{equation}
for all $s=1,2, \cdots, n$ while
\begin{equation}
\partial_t \sum_{l=1}^n A_{ijl}(t,x)\mid_{t=0}=0
\end{equation}
for $i \neq j$.

From such information, is it possible to conclude, together with the smoothness assumption, that
\begin{equation}
\sum_{l=1}^n A_{ijl}(t,x)=e^{-\lambda_i^2 t} \text{ if } i=j \text{ and } 0 \text{ otherwise}
\end{equation}
for all $t \geq 0$?

It seems quite plausible for me, but I cannot really justify my guess for extrapolation to $t>0$. Could anyone please help me?

Edit : I add one more condition that  $A_{ijl}(0,x)=\delta_{il}\delta_{jl}$ so that the above explanation makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These equations are not sufficient to determine $\sum_l A_{ijl}$ for $n>1$.

Here is a counterexample of a solution of the problem in the OP which contradicts the conjectured solution:

set $n=2$, $\lambda_1=0$, $\lambda_2=1$; all elements of $A_{ijl}$ are identically zero, except

$$A_{111}=1-t-t^2/2,\;\;A_{112}=t,$$
$$A_{221}=t,\;\;A_{222}=-1+2e^{-t}.$$

---

More generally, you can take any $F_{ij}(t)=\sum_l A_{ijl}(t)$, and define
$$A_{ijl}=-\left(\sum_{k=2}^n\lambda_k^{-2}\right)^{-1}F'_{ij},\;\;l\geq 2,$$
$$A_{ij1}=F_{ij}+(n-1)\left(\sum_{k=2}^n\lambda_k^{-2}\right)^{-1}F'_{ij}.$$

---

Comment: I am only interested in the sum of $A$ over the index $l$. I don't need details about individual components of $A$. In that case, is my tentative solution on $\sum_l A_{ijl}$ correct?

Comment: So, you mean that my solution plus any such $B$ can be a solution as well? More or less like the gauge transformation?

Comment: Then, I wonder if "all" solutions are characterized by what you just described. Do you have any insight?

Comment: Wait, if the sum of $B$ over $l$ is identically zero,  it does not affect the sum of $A$ over $l$.

Comment: Yes, that is true but $A+B$ will satisfy the same differential equation as just $A$.

Comment: Where no $\sum_l \lambda_l^2 B_{ijl}$ appearing on the right hand side of the equation

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147001/discussion-between-isaac-and-carlo-beenakker).

Comment: Why? There is no differential equation governing $B$ at all. What makes the right-hand side contain $A+B$?

Comment: That you plugged $A+B$ in the left hand side does NOT mean that you can also plug $A+B$ in the right hand side as well..

Comment: I added an explicit counterexample to my answer.

Comment: I see...thank you so much... now I think my next step is to try characterizing all solutions if possible...perhaps do you have any insight?

Comment: I think there is no restriction at all on the solution; I added this to the answer.

Comment: Thank you. Just last question : what if I put another restriction that $\sum_l A_{ijl}$ is bounded for all $t>0 ,x$? Would it make any difference?

Comment: no, as I wrote, you can satisfy the ODE for any function $F_{ij}(t)=\sum_l A_{ijl}(t)$ ; just choose a bounded function.

Comment: By $F$, you mean literally "any" symmetric tensor field? It's time evolution doesn't have to be specified?

Comment: yes, any time dependence will do.